# How can I extract 2 pieces of information output from command though pipes in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a command that produces the following output:

> ```
> {i} count
> {0} 167
>
> real    0m1.370s
> user    0m0.008s
> sys     0m0.000s
> ```

I would like to pipe this output into something that will extract items on line 2 and line 4, and output them in a single line as follows:

```
167 0m1.370s
```

I have often used sed and awk to get a single value, but can i gerrymander these stream tools to process a multiline output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pipe your output to this awk:

```
awk '/\{0\}/{p=$2} /real/{print p, $2; exit}'
```

Comment: Do you really need `next` and `exit` for this small data.  This should work fine: `awk '/\{0\}/{p=$2} /real/{print p, $2}'`

Comment: Yes it will work but both `next` and `exit` are used for efficiency reasons. What if there are thousands of lines after `/real/` pattern. `exit` will terminate awk immediately after printing. `next` definitely can be taken out.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the second element of the second and fourth line you can pipe to the following:

```
awk 'NR==2 {p=$2} NR==4 {print p, $2; exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -vRS='^$' '{print $4, $6}' file
167 0m1.370s
```